# Rust: How to impl an external trait for generic type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to make functionality like this:

```
enum Identifier {
    Number(usize),
    Name(String),
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get<T: Into<Identifier>>(id: T)  -> MyData {
        let id = id.into();
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let a = my_struct.get(42_usize);
let a = my_struct.get("name");
let a = my_struct.get(String::new());
let a = my_struct.get(castable_to_usize);
```

So, i came up with this idea (and similar for usize):

```
impl<T> Into<Identifier> for T
    where T: Into<String>
{
    fn into(self) -> Identifier {
        let name = self.into();
        Identifier::Name(name)
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately, i got a compiler error:

```
Type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type
```

Is there a way to make a bit of polymorphism like this in Rust? I want to pass anything castable to `Identifier` into a function without implementing `Into<Identifier>` for `String`,  `&str` and others manually.

In other words, how can i make any type that is castable to `String` to be castable to `Identifier`?

Comment: Basically, this isn't allowed because any foreign type `Foo` could have its own `impl<T> Into<T> for Foo where T: ...` and if `Identifier` meets its bound on `T` then you have conflicting implementations.

Comment: Oh, thanks, cdhowie. Now i do understand why I can't do that in rust. That makes sense